# Trying to moq a class but am unable to access non interfaced methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

Say if I have an Interface

```
public interface IVehicle<T>
{
    string Drive();
    string Stop();
}
```

And two classes Car() and Aeroplane()

Each has a class which uses the interface to perform actions

```
public class CarActions : IVehicle<Car>
{
    public string Drive()
    {
        return "Go";
    }

    public string Stop()
    {
        return "Stop";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AeroplaneActions : IVehicle<Aeroplane>
{
    public string Drive()
    {
        return "Go";
    }

    public string Stop()
    {
        return "Stop";
    }

    public virtual string Fly()
    {
        return "Fly";
    }     
}
```

When i mock the Aeroplane class, it wont find the fly() method because its not part of the interface

```
  Mock<AeroplaneActions> mockedDirectly = new Mock<AeroplaneActions>();

        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Drive()).Returns("Drive");
        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Stop()).Returns("Stop");
        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Fly()).Returns("Fly");
```

I have tried mocking the Actions class directly which does work, however i will need to change my methods to virtual in this case which i would like to avoid.

```
        Mock<AeroplaneActions> mockedDirectly = new Mock<AeroplaneActions>();

        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Drive()).Returns("Drive");
        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Stop()).Returns("Stop");
        mockedDirectly.Setup(method => method.Fly()).Returns("Fly");
```

I am wondering if there is any other alternatives to this aside from using virtual methods?

Comment: Why are you mocking `AeroplaneActions` - That's your implementation. You should mock the dependency (or interface) - what is it exactly you're trying to test?

Comment: The reason why I tried to mock the `AeroplaneActions` directly is because the method 'fly()' only exists in the implementation.If I try to mock the interface only, I wont be able to access this method as an `IVehicle` only has `drive()` and `stop()`. Should I create more interfaces for any methods which are unique such as `fly()` and test these separately?

Comment: Show the code what you want to test please. Maybe you could use another interface for the `AeroplaneActions`, e.g. `public interface IAeroplane<T> : IVehicle<T>
{
 string Fly();
}`. And then it should be possible to mock this interface `var m = new Mock<IAeroplane<Aeroplane>>()`. Then like this `class AeroplaneActions : IAeroplane<Aeroplane>`.

Comment: I have added this code and its working, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could create another interface for the `AeroplaneActions`, which will inherit from the `IVehicle<T>` and will have the `Fly` method e.g. like this:

```
public interface IAeroplane<T> : IVehicle<T> 
{ 
    string Fly(); 
}.
```

Then class `AeroplaneActions` will implement this interface:

```
AeroplaneActions : IAeroplane<Aeroplane>
```

And then it should be possible to mock this interface:

```
var mock = new Mock<IAeroplane<Aeroplane>>().
```